# When I try and import Image drivers in Python, it says "No module named 'Image'"

Tags: python, display, image

When I import the code from this project: http://frederickvandenbosch.be/?p=1365
and run the code on the Pi, I get this error. I installed the `Adafruit_SSD1306` library and it still does it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The code is on site that I linked to.

If you can't see the photo, the error message says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Image'
```

[image: Running and showing error]

Comment: Did you install PIL with `sudo apt-get install python-imaging`? Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes it is installed, also that library doesn't control an OLED display. If you see the code you will understand. Python-imaging is for imaging formats.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the full code (you only included a small snippet of the code showing the imports, and if I remember correctly, `Image` comes from PIL, and that's the module that isn't found). It might be best to check with the script author on which library they meant by `import Image`.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I fixed it by changing "import Image" to "from PIL import Image" and it now works. Thanks for the help with the PIL stuff.

Comment: You should really be posting code and error messages as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

I changed `import Image` to `from PIL import Image` and it now works.

Comment: This way doesn't work as well... Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I changed import Image to from PIL import Image and tis worked well for me. My context is to make a specific texture for vpython. My system is mac Mojave(10.14) python --version is Python 2.7.9

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers, and in general you should be posting answers which work on a Pi, not on a Mac.